# Node.js exec args don't show up in process.argv

Tags: node.js

If I start a nodejs process at the command line with:

```
node --harmony --regexp-optimization  dist/test.js --foo
```

when I do:

```
console.log(process.argv);
```

I get:

```
[ '/Users/Olegzandr/.nvm/versions/node/v10.6.0/bin/node',
  '/Users/Olegzandr/ores/cli.ts/dist/test.js',
  '--foo' ]
```

just wondering why the exec args don't appear in `process.argv` - will they ever appear? why don't they appear in this case? How do we find out which exec args were used at runtime if we can't read them from `process.argv`?

Answer (score 0):

I forgot about `process.execArgv`:

https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_execargv

exec args don't appear in `process.argv`, but in `process.execArgv`